# Error connecting to Azure: Illegal character in password with mongoose 5.0.1 but works in 4.13.9

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, azure-cosmosdb

I have a node.js application that is deployed to azure using CosmosDB and the MongoDB API.  My application uses mongoose which works seamlessly in 4.13.9.

My application that works connects as follows:

```
var configDB = require('./config/database');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect(configDB.url, { useMongoClient: true } );
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));
```

the config/database file is defined as follows (changed username, password, DB to protect the innocent):

```
module.exports = {
    'url': 'mongodb://azureusername:azurepassword@myazuredb.documents.azure.com:10255/?ssl=true'
}
```

Now the problem comes when I install mongoose 5.0.1.  I remove the useMongoClient option from the connect and got rid of the promise so my connect code is now:

```
mongoose.connect(configDB.url);
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));
```

When this runs I get the following in the console:

> (node:21392) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection (rejection id: 2): Error: Password contains an illegal
>   unescaped character

I can even comment out the connection code to where it is only the mongoose.connect and that is what is giving the error.  What am I doing wrong?  Is there a breaking change in 5.0.1 that I need to account for?  As a side note that may or may not be related, I saw some notes about now giving a callback instead of using promises so if someone has an example of how they do that in a Node/Express app that would be great, but it doesn't seem like that's the isee when I'm getting an error reported on the connect about an illegal character.
NOTE: The config file is exactly the same when running against 4.13.9 or 5.0.1 so I know the password is valid and it is not the issue.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For the latest version (v5.0.1) of Mongoose, you'll need to use this syntax to connect to MongoDB like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://<cosmosdb-username>.documents.azure.com:10255/<databasename>?ssl=true', {
    auth: {
      user: '<cosmosdb-username>',
      password: '<cosmosdb-password>'
    }
  })
  .then(() => console.log('connection successful'))
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

Comment: Where do you get the cosmosDB username from?

Comment: In the portal, you should be able to get the name from the Connection Strings page of the Cosmos DB account. I think it's just the account name.

Comment: You don't *have* to. You just have to urlencode your credentials. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49522847/90674) for details.

Answer (score 9):

The password for the Azure Cosmos DB instance I got ended with `==`, hence the illegal characters message. These characters must be urlencoded.

An equals sign `=` urlencoded is `%3D`.

A properly encoded connection string for the password `jitsu==` could look like `mongodb://user:jitsu%3D%3D@localhost:27017/dbname?ssl=false`.

Also be aware that the connection strings you get from the Cosmos DB blade in the Azure Portal doesn't include the database name.

Answer (score 1):

To connect to local cosmos db emulator use the following connection method (for mongoose > 5.0.0):

```
  mongoose.connect(

  `mongodb://localhost:10255/?ssl=true`,
  {
    auth: {
      user: "localhost",
      password: "C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==",
      dbName: "admin"
    }
  }
);
```

Or you may also do the following:

```
const encodedPassword = encodeURIComponent("C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==");
mongoose.connect(`mongodb://localhost:${encodedPassword}@localhost:10255/admin?ssl=true`);
```

Connection string has following format:

mongodb://username:password@host:port/[database]?ssl=true

and there seems to be some issue with default password character escaping. Thus we encoded it separately.

Answer (score 1):

Add the new url parser as an option `{ useNewUrlParser: true }`

Change you line 3 to:

```
mongoose.connect(configDB.url, { useMongoClient: true, useNewUrlParser: true } );
```