# Why can't my azure web app connect to the cosmos db database?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have been trying to deploy a react based app to Azure and connect it to a cosmosdb in the same resource package using express and mongoose. When I connect to the cloud cosmosdb while running my app locally it works. When I connect from the azure web app to an mlab database that works also. When I try to connect from the webapp deployed on azure to the cosmosdb the connection times out. I can't get the azure resources to communicate!

I have enabled the MongoDB 3.4 wire protocol in the preview settings of my db, but this has not helped the problem. 
Here is my connection code.

```
const mongoUri=mongodb://${process.env.dbName}.documents.azure.com:${process.env.cosmosPort}/?ssl/=true&sslverifycertificate=false`;

mongoose.connect(mongoUri,{ auth: { user: process.env.dbName, password: 
process.env.key }, useNewUrlParser: true }).then(() => 
console.log('connection successful'))
.catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

I expect this to open a connection with the cosmosdb but the log stream shows mongo error connection timed out

Comment: have you checked this?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48994974/timeout-error-when-connecting-to-cosmosdb-with-mongodb-api

Comment: Yes added rules to firewall even turned it off problem persists.

Comment: Are you using the App Service's env variables? Can you `console.log(mongoUri);`?

Comment: Yes have set varibles in the apps settings and mongo uri outputs to logstream

Comment: After turning off Firewall, did you wait ~10 minutes before retrying? Firewall rules can take a bit to apply. Also, there is a specific checkbox in the Cosmos DB Azure Portal to enable Azure datacenter (such is the case of App Service).

Comment: I originally had the Cosmos Setting as 'allow all' following your suggestion has not allowed me to connect. I can't understand why the database connects with my app running locally but not from within the same resource group.

Comment: @WilliamSpruyt - resource groups really have nothing to do with connection issues; they're just organizational containers (allowing you to logically group things together, set permissions for adjusting settings or deleting a service, etc). You can scatter all of your services across many resource groups, or lump them all together; won't make any difference when it comes to how they operate.

Comment: Yes but why can't I connect the app and the database when they are both deployed on azure?

Answer (score 0):

This started to work when I changed the connection code to-

```
mongoose.connect(mongoUri,{ useNewUrlParser: true }).then(() => 
console.log('connection successful'))
.catch((err) => console.error("Ahhhgh! "+ err));`
```

where,

```
const mongoUri = `mongodb://${process.env.dbName}: 
${process.env.key}@${process.env.dbName}.documents.azure.com:10255/mean? 
ssl=true&sslverifycertificate=false`
```

with an @.
Which my blur of frantic research over the past couple of days seems to suggest means the Mongoose or Mongodb version I am using is older than it ought to be. Thanks for comments.